# Pinch to zoom in Unity with touchscreen

Tags: unity, touchscreen

Is there a way to enable pinch-to-zoom in Unity?

It seems like mulititouch is supported with my touchscreen already: When I tip on a window with three fingers, I can move around the window.

But when I try to zoom a website in Firefox, only the text gets selected.

Is there a way to activate the functionality my Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 has under Windows 8?